# NSMapTable WeakMemory does not work in Swift2.0?

Tags: swift

When I am trying to use NSMapTable in swift 2.0, it seems the weak memory option does not work. Here is my test code:

```
class TestClass {
    var a: String
    required init(a: String) {
        self.a = a
    }
}

var table = NSMapTable.strongToWeakObjectsMapTable()

var test: TestClass? = TestClass(a:"name")

table.setObject(test, forKey: "a")

if let object = table.objectForKey("a") {
    print(object)
} else {
    print("nil")
}

test = nil

if let test = test {
    print("test")
} else {
    print("nil")
}

if let object = table.objectForKey("a"), let aa = object as? TestClass {
    print(object)
    print(aa.a)
} else {
    print("nil")
}
```

After I set test to nil ("test = nil"), the table does not return nil for key "a".
The console output is below:

```
TestClass
nil
TestClass
name
```

I also tried NSMapTable with Objective-C, it works fine.

Am I missing something? Or is it a bug of NSMapTable in swift2.0?

Answer (score 1):

`NSMapTable` sometimes does not deallocate keys and objects if weak-weak, weak-strong or strong-weak bindings are there.

If you see `NSMapTable.h` you can find that Apple has mentioned : **entries are not necessarily purged right away when the weak key is reclaimed**

That said, if you try with below, it should release the reference immediately.

```
var table = NSMapTable(keyOptions: .WeakMemory, valueOptions: .WeakMemory)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I replace the key option to .WeakMemory. I found I can not set any objects at all... "var mapTable = NSMapTable(keyOptions: .WeakMemory, valueOptions: .WeakMemory)

var test: TestClass? = TestClass()

mapTable.setObject(test, forKey: test?.key)

print(mapTable)
test = nil
print(mapTable)"

Comment: Yes, that is because, in current context, key does not have any strong reference making compiler believe to release it immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Objectic-C version of the above code.

```
NSMapTable *mapTable = [[NSMapTable alloc] initWithKeyOptions:NSPointerFunctionsStrongMemory valueOptions:NSPointerFunctionsWeakMemory capacity:10];

TestClass *testObject = [[TestClass alloc] initWithName:@"a"];

[mapTable setObject:testObject forKey:@"a"];

NSLog(@"%@", mapTable);
testObject = nil;
NSLog(@"%@", mapTable);
```

This piece of code works fine and just returns what I want. When I set testObject to nil. the mapTable becomes empty immediately. Output below:

```
2015-10-22 09:15:54.635 Test[1162:20183] NSMapTable {
[8] a -> <TestClass: 0x7fbf7350cc40>
}
2015-10-22 09:15:54.637 Test[1162:20183] NSMapTable {
}
```

My Question : Why does NSMapTable behave differently in Swift ?

Comment: See my answer above re Objective-C vs. Swift NSMapTable functionality.

Answer (score 1):

"NSMapTable’s focus on strong and weak references means that Swift’s prevalent value types are a no-go—reference types only, please."

http://nshipster.com/nshashtable-and-nsmaptable/